# how to compare matlab cells or structs

Tags: matlab, struct, cells

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Octave/MATLAB: How to compare structs for equality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951828/octave-matlab-how-to-compare-structs-for-equality)

is there a simple comparison function for matlab cell or struct objects?
using '==' doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: This question has been marked as a duplicate; however, this question is older then the one being compared to. The newer question should be marked as the duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to know if two cell arrays or struct objects are exactly equal you could always use [isequaln](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isequaln.html).

Comment: This will not work if any of the structure fields contains a NaN. You can also not call isnan for a struct to know if there is a problem in the first place. This makes it a rather unreliable general purpose comparison method.

Comment: Actually, you should use isequalwithequalnans for this. See [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951828/octave-matlab-how-to-compare-structs-for-equality).

Comment: In R2012b there is now the more concisely named [isequaln](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isequaln.html) function.

Answer (score 6):

Use `isequal` to compare two cells. Note however that `==` is not advised even for arrays:

```
>> A = [1 2 3 4 5];
>> B = [1 2 3 4 5];
>> A == B
ans =

     1     1     1     1     1
```

You would need to use a further trick to use that expression in a if statement for instance.

The reason `==` is not recommended for variables of type `double` is because of the IEEE 754 representation use by MATLAB. For instance:

```
  >> .1 + .1 + .1 == .3

  ans =

       0
```

To compare double values more robustly, you can use the `abs` function in MATLAB:

```
>> if ( abs( (.1+.1+.1) - .3 ) < 1e-10 ); disp('Values are pretty close although not necessarily bit equal'); end
Values are pretty close although not necessarily bit equal
>>
```