# comparing files in matlab with a boolean output

Tags: matlab, diff

I'm trying to compare two .mat files in matlab. I'm using the `visdiff` command. 
It provides a html output. I want to get boolean output: `true` - when both the files are identical, `false` - when the files don't match.
 Is it possible to get a boolean output from the visdiff command?
 If not possible is there any other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the mat file, then it is a struct. Comparing structs is already explained in [Octave/MATLAB: How to compare structs for equality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951828/octave-matlab-how-to-compare-structs-for-equality)

```
isequaln(load(a),load(b))
```